# How to detect user inactivity using Angular 2?

Tags: javascript, angular, browser

I am trying to create an Angular App which contains videos where the user needs to be logged out after a few minutes of inactivity.

- If the user is watching the videos either normally or in fullscreen, he need not be logged out.
- If the tab is inactive and the videos are playing I need him to be logged out after inactivity.

Comment: make use of a directive that check for mouse movements or clcik on the window and on setTimeout if nothing happens for that time frame log the user out

Comment: When viewing the video in fullscreen the cursor disappears, and then i go back to square one again.

Answer (score 7):

The ***easiest*** way will be to use [idlejs](https://github.com/harunurhan/idlejs).

It works well with Angular and it includes .d.ts bindings for Typescript.

```
import { Idle } from 'idlejs/dist';

// with predefined events on `document`
const idle = new Idle()
  .whenNotInteractive()
  .within(60)
  .do(() => console.log('Logout user with a function'))
  .start();
```

When a user is playing a video you can stop the idle.

```
play(){
    this.idle.stop();
    // play movie
}
```

And when the user clicks pause / stop

```
pause(){
    this.idle.restart();
    // pause movie
}
```